# MySQL Insert Data Question

Tags: php, sql, mysql, insert

assume I already created a table in MySQL as below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `client_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `order_time` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sub_total` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_cost` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_cost` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sales`
--
```

If I added a new field **must_fill** for the current table.

```
 `must_fill` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

User can insert less than the number of fiels items to the table defaultly, just as the script of below.

```
INSERT INTO `sales` (`id`, `client_id`, `order_time`, `sub_total`, `shipping_cost`, `total_cost`) VALUES
(8, 12312, '2007-12-19 01:30:45', 10.75, 3.00, 13.75);
```

It's fine.

But How can I configure the field (must_fill) to a MUST INCLUDE Data field when user plan to insert into new data.

BTW, The code will be integrated in PHP script.

[update]
Or, can I only write special PHP script to judge **must_fill** is null or not when user try to run a Insert Into script binded some data values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to enforce this as MySQL was never designed in quite that way. A `NOT NULL` designation in a MySQL table merely means the value can never be `NULL`, not that a value *must* be supplied: MySQL will find a default if it is omitted. However, you can provide a default value that would be annoying if a real one was omitted; exactly what to use depends on your application.

I would also look at [MySQL Server Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html). You might want to enable `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`, but that's a fairly draconian setting and your application will probably break if it has been programmed against MySQL's lax defaults regime.

Answer (score 0):

Not even a `check constraint` prevents MySQL from inserting the implicit default for an integer:

```
create table YourTable (
  id int primary key
, must_fill tinyint not null
, constraint must_fill_constraint check (must_fill <> 0)
);
insert into YourTable (id) values (1);
select must_fill from YourTable t1;
```

This prints `0`, even though there is a constraint forbidding `0`.  You can change this behavior my enabling [strict mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables).

Comment: MySQL doesn't support check constraints. It parses them but does not store the constraint.  It silently ignores them.  This is one of my biggest complaints about MySQL.

Comment: @Bill Karwin: Thanks, you're right. Can't believe I forgot that :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will default an integer column like your must_fill to zero if you do not specify "strict mode". Try adding a

SET SESSION sql_mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES

before the INSERT, and your example INSERT should now produce an error because no value was supplied for the must_fill column.

You can set strict mode as a command line option when you launch the MySQL daemon. Details are in the MySQL mode documentation page I mention below.

MySQL modes
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html